# VSCode/Flutter project, IOS testing issues

Tags: flutter, firebase, cocoapods, mobile-application

I have an app called CYKE AI which i released recently to the play store(Android), I have recently got a macbook so that I can work on releasing the ios version as well.

NOTE: This project uses firebase, glassfy, google ads, google sign-in, google subscriptions and a ton of different things from pub.dev

On my windows pc the project works perfectly, I moved the project using a usb to the mac, I've went through and done all of the required set ups to make sure that the project should run smoothly on mac. This includes installing flutter. vscode, xcode, android studio and cocoapods (not sure why this gave me an issue but I did install it using homebrew)

After getting my project open I then went and set up firebase for the ios part of it using the following documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

I've been trying to run this project for the past 3 days, using different solutions I've found on the net, trying new things, reinstalling the IDEs, Ive even created a new project just to see if its maybe the emulators that are the issue, but on a new project everything runs fine.
Whats crazy to me is that not even the android version runs on the mac, i will attach some of the errors I've been getting, there are allot of "fixes" that I've found but none of these work.

I'm new to app development on mac and I just cannot figure out what the issue could be, I'm open to testing out fixes and posing the results in hopes that i can get this to work.

After getting cocoapods to work this is the furthest I've gone, the following error comes up:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           37.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/AppAuth/AppAuth.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/BoringSSL-GRPC/BoringSSL-GRPC.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/gRPC-C++/gRPC-C++.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/abseil/abseil.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/gRPC-Core/gRPC-Core.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/leveldb-library/leveldb-library.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/Flutter/Flutter.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/Glassfy/Glassfy.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GlassfyGlue/GlassfyGlue.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.debug.xcconfig:0:0
Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/firebase_core/firebase_core.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/Try/Try.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/device_info_plus/device_info_plus.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/flutter_tts/flutter_tts.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/glassfy_flutter/glassfy_flutter.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/google_sign_in_ios/google_sign_in_ios.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/open_filex/open_filex.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/package_info_plus/package_info_plus.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/path_provider_foundation/path_provider_foundation.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/rive_common/rive_common.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/share_plus/share_plus.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/shared_preferences_foundation/shared_preferences_foundation.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/speech_to_text/speech_to_text.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/url_launcher_ios/url_launcher_ios.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/video_player_avfoundation/video_player_avfoundation.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): unable to open configuration settings file
/Users/mac/Desktop/chat%20gpt%20v%2018/ios/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/wakelock/wakelock.debug.xcconfig:0:0

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC-C++/gRPC-C++.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Glassfy/Glassfy.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.modulemap

Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist'

Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist'

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/open_filex/open_filex.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/leveldb-library/leveldb-library.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Try/Try.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/speech_to_text/speech_to_text.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/GlassfyGlue/GlassfyGlue.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/path_provider_foundation/path_provider_foundation.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_tts/flutter_tts.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/BoringSSL-GRPC/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap
Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/abseil/abseil.modulemap

Error (Xcode): missing module map file: '/Users/mac/Desktop/chat gpt v 18/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC-Core/gRPC-Core.modulemap

Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist'

Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist'
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited
```

Comment: Have you performed pod install command in project directory on your mac system